# Raw Code UIImage in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

Would anyone know how to create a UIImage out of raw code in swift? I've looked at many other types of questions to see if it was mentioned anywhere, but as far as I've seen, no one has said anything about it.

I just want to work in the ViewController, and completely ignore the main storyboard. I'm wondering if it's possible or not...

Comment: What do you mean "out of raw code"? Do you not have an image at all?

Comment: i have an image, i was wondering if there was a way to programmatically insert it into a frame made only from code, not inserted into an image from the storyboard.

Comment: yes, see my answer. You can create an app entirely in code.

Answer (score 0):

First off... working in code alone is where everything started. There is no need for Storyboards or Xibs at all in your project. You can do everything without them. All they do is add convenience editors to make it more visual to create your project.

You can create an image from a file in code like...

```
let image = UIImage(named: "TheNameOfYourImage")
```

If you want to create a UIImageView you can do it like this...

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

If you are not sure how to do something your first place to go is Google...

[This is the documentation for UIImage.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage)

Comment: Ive tried it, that was what we were told to do via the playground we were provided. For some reason, the error "Instance member 'image' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'. I was told to make the frame first, but the issue persisted, so i ended up with this:                                                      `let image = UIImage(named: "imagename.png")
    let myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 100))
    var imageView = UIImageView()` I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: I think you need to find a tutorial or something. What you are taking about is the very very basics of iOS development. Any beginner tutorial will go over this. There is no property "image" on UIViewController. You need to add an image view as a sub Jew of the view. What I am saying will make zero sense unless you go through a tutorial first.